# Spinnaker deployment in kubernetes is failing

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

**Background:** I have setup a ServiceAccount and spinnaker-role-binding in the default namespace. Created the spinnaker namespace for Kubernetes. Deployed services on port 9000 and 8084.

```
NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/spin-deck-np   LoadBalancer    hidden          <pending>     9000:31295/TCP   9m39s
service/spin-gate-np   LoadBalancer    hidden          <pending>     8084:32161/TCP   9m39s
```

Created halyard deployment in the default namespace and configured hal inside it.

**Problem:** When I run the `hal deploy apply` command then I am getting below error

```
Problems in Global:
! ERROR Unexpected exception:
  io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: GET
  at:
  https://kubernetes.default/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/spinnaker/replicasets.
  Message: the server could not find the requested resource. Received status:
  Status(apiVersion=v1, code=404, details=StatusDetails(causes=[], group=null,
  kind=null, name=null, retryAfterSeconds=null, uid=null,
  additionalProperties={}), kind=Status, message=the server could not find the
  requested resource, metadata=ListMeta(resourceVersion=null, selfLink=null,
  additionalProperties={}), reason=NotFound, status=Failure,
  additionalProperties={}).
```

Below is my kube config file at /home/spinnaker/.kube/config

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
    server: https://kubernetes.default
  name: default
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: default
    user: user
  name: default
current-context: default
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: user
  user:
    token: *********************
```

Below is the hal config file at /home/spinnaker/.hal/config

> ```
> currentDeployment: default
> deploymentConfigurations:
> - name: default
>   version: 1.8.1
>   providers:
>     appengine:
>       enabled: false
>       accounts: []
>     aws:
>       enabled: false
>       accounts: []
>       bakeryDefaults:
>         baseImages: []
>       defaultKeyPairTemplate: '{{name}}-keypair'
>       defaultRegions:
>       - name: us-west-2
>       defaults:
>         iamRole: BaseIAMRole
>     ecs:
>       enabled: false
>       accounts: []
>     azure:
>       enabled: false
>       accounts: []
>       bakeryDefaults:
>         templateFile: azure-linux.json
>         baseImages: []
>     dcos:
>       enabled: false
>       accounts: []
>       clusters: []
>     dockerRegistry:
>       enabled: true
>       accounts:
>       - name: my-docker-registry
>         requiredGroupMembership: []
>         providerVersion: V1
>         permissions: {}
>         address: https://index.docker.io
>         email: fake.email@spinnaker.io
>         cacheIntervalSeconds: 30
>         clientTimeoutMillis: 60000
>         cacheThreads: 1
>         paginateSize: 100
>         sortTagsByDate: false
>         trackDigests: false
>         insecureRegistry: false
>         repositories:
>         - library/nginx
>       primaryAccount: my-docker-registry
>     google:
>       enabled: false
>       accounts: []
>       bakeryDefaults:
>         templateFile: gce.json
>         baseImages: []
>         zone: us-central1-f
>         network: default
>         useInternalIp: false
>     kubernetes:
>       enabled: true
>       accounts:
>       - name: my-k8s-account
>         requiredGroupMembership: []
>         providerVersion: V1
>         permissions: {}
>         dockerRegistries:
>         - accountName: my-docker-registry
>           namespaces: []
>         configureImagePullSecrets: true
>         cacheThreads: 1
>         namespaces: []
>         omitNamespaces: []
>         kinds: []
>         omitKinds: []
>         customResources: []
>         cachingPolicies: []
>         kubeconfigFile: /home/spinnaker/.kube/config
>         oauthScopes: []
>         oAuthScopes: []
>       primaryAccount: my-k8s-account
>     openstack:
>       enabled: false
>       accounts: []
>       bakeryDefaults:
>         baseImages: []
>     oracle:
>       enabled: false
>       accounts: []
>   deploymentEnvironment:
>     size: SMALL
>     type: Distributed
>     accountName: my-k8s-account
>     updateVersions: true
>     consul:
>       enabled: false
>     vault:
>       enabled: false
>     customSizing: {}
>     gitConfig:
>       upstreamUser: spinnaker
>   persistentStorage:
>     persistentStoreType: gcs
>     azs: {}
>     gcs:
>       jsonPath: /home/spinnaker/.gcp/gcs-account.json
>       project: round-reality
>       bucket: spin-94cc2e22-8ece-4bc1-80fd-e9df71c1d9f4
>       rootFolder: front50
>       bucketLocation: us
>     redis: {}
>     s3:
>       rootFolder: front50
>     oracle: {}
>   features:
>     auth: false
>     fiat: false
>     chaos: false
>     entityTags: false
>     jobs: false
>   metricStores:
>     datadog:
>       enabled: false
>     prometheus:
>       enabled: false
>       add_source_metalabels: true
>     stackdriver:
>       enabled: false
>     period: 30
>     enabled: false
>   notifications:
>     slack:
>       enabled: false
>   timezone: America/Los_Angeles
>   ci:
>     jenkins:
>       enabled: false
>       masters: []
>     travis:
>       enabled: false
>       masters: []
>   security:
>     apiSecurity:
>       ssl:
>         enabled: false
>       overrideBaseUrl: http://External IP of worker:8084
>     uiSecurity:
>       ssl:
>         enabled: false
>       overrideBaseUrl: http://External IP of worker:9000
>     authn:
>       oauth2:
>         enabled: false
>         client: {}
>         resource: {}
>         userInfoMapping: {}
>       saml:
>         enabled: false
>       ldap:
>         enabled: false
>       x509:
>         enabled: false
>       iap:
>         enabled: false
>       enabled: false
>     authz:
>       groupMembership:
>         service: EXTERNAL
>         google:
>           roleProviderType: GOOGLE
>         github:
>           roleProviderType: GITHUB
>         file:
>           roleProviderType: FILE
>       enabled: false
>   artifacts:
>     bitbucket:
>       enabled: false
>       accounts: []
>     gcs:
>       enabled: false
>       accounts: []
>     github:
>       enabled: false
>       accounts: []
>     gitlab:
>       enabled: false
>       accounts: []
>     http:
>       enabled: false
>       accounts: []
>     s3:
>       enabled: false
>       accounts: []
>   pubsub:
>     google:
>       enabled: false
>       subscriptions: []
>   canary:
>     enabled: false
>     serviceIntegrations:
>     - name: google
>       enabled: false
>       accounts: []
>       gcsEnabled: false
>       stackdriverEnabled: false
>     - name: prometheus
>       enabled: false
>       accounts: []
>     - name: datadog
>       enabled: false
>       accounts: []
>     - name: aws
>       enabled: false
>       accounts: []
>       s3Enabled: false
>     reduxLoggerEnabled: true
>     defaultJudge: NetflixACAJudge-v1.0
>     stagesEnabled: true
>     templatesEnabled: true
>     showAllConfigsEnabled: true
> ```

Used below commands in hal to interact with kubernetes

```
kubectl config set-cluster default --server=https://kubernetes.default --certificate-authority=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
kubectl config set-context default --cluster=default
token=$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)
kubectl config set-credentials user --token=$token
kubectl config set-context default --user=user
kubectl config use-context default
```

How could I resolve the error for spinnaker deployment?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As per your config file it's looking like kubeconfig context(Search it) not setup correctly.

**Please use below command**

```
# Setting Variable for admin kubeconfig file location(Please fetch config file with --admin - if possible)       
kubeconfig_path="<my-k8s-account-admin-file-path>"

hal config provider kubernetes account add my-k8s-account --provider-version v2 \
--kubeconfig-file "$kubeconfig_path" \
--context $(kubectl config current-context --kubeconfig "$kubeconfig_path")
```

After execution of above command you will be able to see context in your config file, which is missing in current config.